# Extracting unique value sequences from DF column with R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following data frame:

```
Col1 Col2
1    A
1    B
1    C
2    A
2    B
2    C
3    D
3    B
3    C
3    F
4    A
4    B
4    C
```

I'd like to extract unque sequence vectors (bus line stop sequences) from Col2 (actual stops of a particular bus route) where each sequence is defined by Col1 (respective bus route IDs) in R. The multiple occurence of identical sequences are unimportant. So, the desired outputs are:

`A, B, C` (in cases of Col1=1, 2 and 4) and 
`D, B, C, F` (in case of Col1=3)

Comment: `unique(with(df, tapply(Col2, Col1, toString)))` comes to mind

Comment: or `unique(aggregate(Col2 ~ Col1, df, toString)$Col2)`

Comment: This latter is a good step, but: 1.) Original sequence order must be maintained (your solution gives alphabetic order if printed), 2.) It seems to merge all possible sequences into one "supersequence". I need all the possible sequence variations.

Comment: please provide precise expected result

Comment: The sequence remains the same with all the solutions posted so far. As @HubertL commented, please provide expected output

Answer (score 2):

You could split up the vector of bus stops according to the vector of route IDs. This will return a list of character vectors, on which you can call `unique` to remove the duplicated vectors (keeping the first occurrence).

Calling `toString` on each of these vectors through `sapply` will then convert the list of vectors to a vector of comma-separated strings.

```
res <- sapply(unique(split(df$Col2, df$Col1)), toString)
print(res)
```

Comment: at least put some work to make them strings and unlist - Good idea though

Comment: something like `sapply(unique(split(df$Col2, df$Col1)), toString)` will do the trick

Comment: @Sotos The format of the output was not specified, so I concentrated on the core of the solution. Also I think my solution is closer to the description of 'sequence vectors' than your comma-separated string.

Comment: Comma separated is specified in the Q. If you edit with some explanation and display the output It will at least be more complete as an answer and any downvotes will be removed

Answer (score 0):

From your question I have understood that you want the unique sequences for each col1 id. In order to test I changed your data a bit (and I used the data.table package). What you could try is the following:

```
require(data.table)
df <- fread('Col1 Col2
              1    A
              1    B
              1    C
              2    A
              2    B
              2    C
              1    A
              1    B
              1    C
              3    D
              3    B
              3    C
              3    F
              1    A
              1    F
              1    C
              4    A
              4    B
              4    C')
```

In your case, if your data frame is called df just do `setDT(df)` to turn it into a data table.
And from this data table select the unique sequences in Col2 by:

```
df[, .(list(Col2), Col1), by = rleid(Col1)][,.(Sequence = unique(V1)), by = Col1]
```

Which gives:

```
    Col1 Sequence
1:    1    A,B,C
2:    1    A,F,C
3:    2    A,B,C
4:    3  D,B,C,F
5:    4    A,B,C
```

What the command does is the following: 
Fist, for every ID in Col1 I get the sequence in Col2 (I use the rleid function to identify continuous IDs in Col1). Then, I select the unique sequences by each Col1 value.